# Add whitespace to string every 3 characters in Jinja2

Tags: html, jinja2

I have a source of youtube viewcounts, and I want to represent them separated every 3 characters.

Examples:
My source is 1897584, I want it to be: 1 897 584;
1200, I want it to be: 1 200...
234989, 234 989...
123, 123...
and so on...

Is it possible to split the string every 3 characters using only jinja2?

Cheers in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's doable. You have to make a [custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) - a python function - in your python file. This would do the job:

```python
def number_format(nr):
    list_nr = [i for i in reversed(nr)]
    list_nr_three = ["".join(list_nr[i:i+3]) for i in range(0, len(list_nr), 3)]
    str_nr = " ".join(list_nr_three)
    return str_nr[::-1]
```

And then [add your custom filter](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/api/#custom-filters) to your jinja environment:

```
environment.filters['number_format'] = number_format
```

And you can use it in your template file like so:

```
{{ '1897584'|number_format }}
```

Comment: Thanks, that would do it!